# Django : Using the register form i gave the url in the lastline for redirecting to the loginpage it is not getting it is showing the page not found

Tags: javascript, python, html, mysql, django

[when i click the login button here im getting page not found..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrNdF.png)
[This is my template file i gave like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8e6fo.png) 
[im getting like this error plz any one can solve this im new Django framework](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgOqw.png)

Im trying to click the login button but it not redirecting to the login page it getting like the page is not found i gave the correct url

```
<a href="{% url 'login' %}"
```

but im not getting plz any solve this issue
urls.py
from django.urls import path
from .views import crud
from .views import auth

app_name = 'members'

urlpatterns = [
path('hello/', crud.index, name='index'),#views filename and index is the function name
path('add/', crud.add, name='add'),
#ADDING THE NEW USER
path('add/addrecord/', crud.addrecord, name='addrecord'),
#DELETE ROUTE
path('delete/int:id', crud.delete, name='delete'),
#UPDATE ROUTES
path('update/int:id', crud.update, name='update'),
path('update/updaterecord/int:id', crud.updaterecord, name='updaterecord'),
#LOGIN $ REGISTER ROUTES..

```
path("register/", auth.register, name="register"),
path("login/", auth.login_user, name="login"),
path('', auth.home, name='home'),
```

Comment: please provide main project urls and app urls and register template

Comment: i had already gave the urls and templatefile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try this way:

In your main project urls.py file:

```
urlpatterns = [
  path('members/',include('members.urls','url'),namepspace='member')#here just add namespace after include and added url after member.urls
]
```

And in your template:

```
<a href="{% url 'member:login' %}">
```

Try this way and check if it solves that problem

Comment: include() got an unexpected keyword argument 'namepspace'

Comment: ok i got it. just remove member from namespace add url in namespace. To see this modification just checkout my answer

Comment: Thankq very much bro itsworking

Comment: path('members/',include('members.urls', namespace="member")), i used like this  i used the namespace in the include then it is working

Comment: Above code is working right? It means my first answer is working before modification

Comment: And also don't forget to accept my answer

Comment: Bro its working ur code is working but when i used that im got an error like  add namespace in the include . i had added the namespace in the include then the error is gone thanks very much im trying since oneday bro could  you give me any email id or number  for any queries if you dont mind

Comment: ok manoj tq very much if i get any erros further  i  will send mail to u plz respond

Comment: here you didn't accept my answer

Comment: How to accept the ans broo i dont know im new to stockoverflow

Comment: Done bro i  accepted

Comment: HI manoj i had sent mail to u plz respond to that

Answer (score 0):

You made a typo `<a href="{% url 'login'}"` , you are missing a `%`

Try this way:

```
<a href="{% url 'login' %}">
```

Comment: i have use like that but it is not getting

Comment: What is the url now?

Comment: i used like this <a href="{%url  'member:login' %}">

Comment: And what did u get?

Comment: it is redirecting bro issue is resolved

Answer (score 0):

Kindly close the  tag and it will work.
`<a class="" href="{% url 'login' %}" > <i class=""></i>Login </a>`